# What does the variable array name at the end of the structure's definition means?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, declaration

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137927/what-does-the-variable-name-at-the-end-of-the-structures-definition-means) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions) but it seems they're not exactly my situtation.

I have a code like this

```
struct ppl_weight {
    uint16_t weight;
    uint8_t weightHour;

} ppl_weightList[16];
```

but I can't understand the array at the end of the `struct`. What does it mean? Have I an array of 16 `struct`? How does I manage this data type?

Comment: Yes, `ppl_weightList` is an array of 16 structs. You can access it like any other array. For more help you might provide more details where your doubts are.

Comment: As you said, you have an`ppl_weight ` array size of 16. It is the same as `int x[16]` but the data type is the `ppl_weight ` struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a declaration of an array with 16 elements of the type `struct ppl_weight`. You could split this declaration

```
struct ppl_weight {
    uint16_t weight;
    uint8_t weightHour;

} ppl_weightList[16];
```

the following way

```
struct ppl_weight {
    uint16_t weight;
    uint8_t weightHour;

};

struct ppl_weight ppl_weightList[16];
```

Answer (score 1):

We can declare structure variables at the time of defining structure as follows

```
struct packet
{
  int range;
  char head;
}p1, p2, p3;
```